# How to pass `std::string` to `QString` `arg` method?

Tags: c++, qt, templates

```
class StringResourceTable
{
private:
    StringResourceTable();

public:
    static StringResourceTable& instance();

    void configure(const QString& path);
    QString message(const QString& id) const;

    template <typename T1>
    QString message(const QString& id, T1 a1) const
    {
        return message(id).arg(a1);
    }

    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    QString message(const QString& id, T1 a1, T2 a2) const
    {
        return message(id).arg(a1).arg(a2);
    }

    template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
    QString message(const QString& id, T1 a1, T2 a2, T3 a3) const
    {
        return message(id).arg(a1).arg(a2).arg(a3);
    }

private:
    QString m_path;
    QMap<QString, QString> m_map;
}
```

This code uses the `arg` method if `QString` class to substitute `%1`, `%2`, ... by some parameters. Parameters may be int, char*, double and whatever `QString` supports, but not `std::string`. It would be very convenient to pass `std::string` to any of `message` functions. I cant specialize them for `std::string` because its order is not defined. It may be first, second, ...

I think it should be a template struct which will convert `std::string` to `QString` using its `.c_str()` method. Who can help in writing it ?

Comment: It is annoying that QString::arg() has no overload for std::string and std::wstring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about [fromStdString](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#fromStdString) function?

However, you can use something like

```
template<typename T>
const T& convert(const T& v)
{
   return v;
}

QString convert(const std::string& s)
{
   return QString::fromStdString(s);
}
```

and use like

```
return message(id).arg(convert(a1));
```

Comment: But how it should work when passing int for example. It should be something template to work for other types too